# UITableViewCell Item selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm adding `UIButton` in `UITableView`, I'm trying to change `UIButton background color`, `UIButton title color` and `UIButton image color` on table view  cell selection and same vice versa.

MY Code is

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
         let propertyCell = tablePropertyList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PropertyListTableCell

        propertyCell.buttonDownload.selected = true
        propertyCell.buttonDownload.setTitleColor(utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xf8f8f8), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "DownloadSelected")!

        propertyCell.buttonDownload.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        propertyCell.buttonDownload.backgroundColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x006747)
        propertyCell.buttonDownload.layer.borderColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x006747).CGColor

    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let propertyCell = tablePropertyList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PropertyListTableCell

        propertyCell.buttonDownload.selected = false
        propertyCell.buttonDownload.setTitleColor(utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x006747), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "Download")!

        propertyCell.buttonDownload.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        propertyCell.buttonDownload.backgroundColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xf8f8f8)
        propertyCell.buttonDownload.layer.borderColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xf8f8f8).CGColor

 }
```

//on UIButton Action
MY Code is

```
func downloadViewAction(sender: UIButton)
    {
        sender.selected = true
        sender.setTitleColor(utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xf8f8f8), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "DownloadSelected")!

        sender.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        sender.backgroundColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x006747)
        sender.layer.borderColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x006747).CGColor

        print("inside ownload action view")
        let splitView:UISplitViewController = DevelopmemtSplitViewController()
        if let path = tablePropertyList.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let selectedproperty = propertyArray[path.row]
            self.showActivityIndicator(splitView.view, message: "Downloading properties for "+selectedproperty)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not getting your question, can you tell, what problem you are facing in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

awakeFromNib method of cell class can be used to change  titlecolor, image of button based on state. Please refer following code

```
   class PropertyListTableCell : UITableViewCell
    {
     func awakeFromNib()
         {
        propertyCell.buttonDownload.setTitleColor(utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x006747), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

      propertyCell.buttonDownload.setTitleColor(utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xf8f8f8), forState: UIControlState.Selected)

        }
    }

func downloadViewAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    sender.selected = true //automatically changes titlecolor of button
}
```

Comment: are you using  awakeFromNib in cell?

Comment: Even if  you use StoryBoard. You can use awakefromNib to set properties of buttons based on normal or selected state.

Comment: ohk,i got it but there is problem yet when i tap on button its color not changing and also i want tableview cell to be seleted when its button is tapped or clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right. You have a button inside every `PropertyListTableCell` and you want to change the way that button looks depending on the selection state of the cell.
If so, overwrite the `setSelected(_:animated:)` function in your `PropertyListTableCell` class, this way, whenever a cell is selected or deselect the button appearance will change automatically.

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: true);

    if (selected) {
        self.buttonDownload.backgroundColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x006747)
        self.buttonDownload.layer.borderColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x006747).CGColor
    }
    else {
        propertyCell.buttonDownload.backgroundColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xf8f8f8)
        propertyCell.buttonDownload.layer.borderColor = utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xf8f8f8).CGColor
    }

    self.buttonDownload.selected = true;
}
```

As commented Savitha above, the button image and the title color can be defined just once in the `awakeFromNib` (for example).

And there is no need to change any visual in the button action function because it's done when selecting the cell:

```
func downloadViewAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let cell = sender as! as! PropertyListTableCell;
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell);
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None);

     print("inside ownload action view")
     let selectedproperty = propertyArray[path.row]
     self.showActivityIndicator(splitView.view, message: "Downloading properties for "+selectedproperty)
}
```